# Edit Regular Expression from Java to JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Hi i have a problem with RegEx i have my expression in Java for split input to arrays, but this expression don't work in JavaScript:

```
(?<=</d[12]>)\\d*(?=<d[12]>)
```

I have some dialogue

`<d1>bla bla bla</d1><d2>bla bla bla</d2><d1>bla bla bla</d1>`

And i want to output split into array `[<d1>bla bla bla</d1>,<d2>bla bla bla</d2>,<d1>bla bla bla</d1>]`

Can you help me how i edit this expression? Thanks.

Comment: javascript won't support lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split your input string like you did in java because javascript won't support lookbehind assertions.

And this will work for this specific case.

```
> var s = "<d1>bla bla bla</d1><d2>bla bla bla</d2><d1>bla bla bla</d1>"
undefined
> s.match(/(?!\d+).*?<\/d[12]>(?=\d*<d[12]>|$)/g)
[ '<d1>bla bla bla</d1>',
  '<d2>bla bla bla</d2>',
  '<d1>bla bla bla</d1>' ]
```